# Auto-updating fields in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio

Is it possible to have a field in Visio 2003 that will update to the current date when the file is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Visio 2003 available at the moment to try this out, but it looks like you can [add a date/time field with Text Tool](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HA011822491033.aspx) which will display the date when the document was created, revised, or printed or the current
 date or time.